# PostgreSQL query to Supabase Query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, supabase

How can i make once of this PostgreSQL querys in supabase?
I tried reading supabase doc but it doesn't work

```
select rooms.id as room_id, members.id as member_id, user_id from rooms 
inner join members 
on rooms.id = members.room_id 
where rooms.id = members.room_id

and user_id = 1
```

Or

```
select room_id, user_id, members.id from members 
inner join rooms 
on rooms.id = members.room_id 
where members.user_id = 1
```

Comment: What error are you getting? How are you running the query?

Comment: You might need to consider creating a view for the data and then selecting the view in your client library

Answer (score 2):

No, there's not really any performance difference from calling an `.rpc()` vs. just calling the api directly.  You should be fine.  Just make sure to set up your database correctly (indexes, joins, etc.) for best performance.

Answer (score 2):

Hello this might not be supabase specific solution, but in my case what I do use when I need to run custom queries like in your own case here is to use the `pg` package from npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg.

- I would just create a client and parse my supabase db credentials to it.

  ```
  export const pgClient = () => {
      console.error(`using Postgres ${process.env.host}`)
      const client = new Client({
        user: process.env.user,
        host: process.env.host,
        database: process.env.database,
        password: process.env.password,
        port: parseInt(process.env.port!)
      })
      return client
  }
  ```
- export it to my router and simply connect

  ```
  const client = pgClient()
  await client.connect()
  ```
- Run my custom query directly on the DB

  ```
  await client.query("SELECT * from auth.users")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can query a foreign table using the Supabase client, but only if there's a foreign key set up:

[Supabase select(): Query foreign tables](https://supabase.io/docs/reference/javascript/select#query-foreign-tables)

As stated in the comments, you can create a `view` for this purpose:

[Create View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createview.html)

Or you can create a [PosgreSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createfunction.html) and call that with [Supabase `.rpc()`](https://supabase.io/docs/reference/javascript/rpc):

Comment: Will there be an impact on performance if I create a function to filter the data and do complex things like left join and pagination and call this function whenever the user wants to fetch data and when it reaches 10 rows it calls the function again to fetch the other rows and so on...